# Any difference between “shouldn’t have done something” and "shouldn’t have to do something”?

Tags: past-tense, participles

Is there any difference between these two?

1. I shouldn’t have **done** that.
2. I shouldn’t have **to do** that.

Comment: The first means that doing 'that' in the past was a mistake; the second means that you should not be required to do 'that' now or in the future.

Comment: Another difference is that they're pronounced differently. _Have_ in the first one is pronounced with a /v/, while in the second one it's pronounced with an /f/. That's the way people tell them apart in speech.

Comment: @JohnLawler Unlike finite forms of _have to_, where the voicing assimilation is mandatory, I find it completely optional here. Much more essentially, I tell them apart in speech by the latter being /hav ~ haf/ and the former being /ə ~ əv/; and by the latter being stressed and the former unstressed.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Mmm-hmmm. Reduced idiomatic constructions and their fæspič variants are always fascinating. I have no doubt we'd tune to each other's channels immediately viva voce, but then that's what humans are good at.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's the same construction as *I shouldn't have answered this* **vs** *I shouldn't have to answer this*. The latter is a complaint and indicative that not only did I not answer but that I will not answer in the future, while the former indicates that I did answer but now regret it.